# Prove that if $f'_{-}$ exists and is continuous $(a,b)$ then $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)=f'_{-}(x)$ for $x\in (a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Prove that if $f'_{-}$ exists and is continuous  $(a,b)$ then $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)=f'_{-}(x)$ for $x\in (a,b)$.

We know that $$\inf\{f'_{-}(x):x\in(x,x+h)\}\leq \frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h}\leq \sup\{f'_{-}(x):x\in(x,x+h)\}.$$

for $x\in(a,b)$ and $h>0$ such that $x+h\in (a,b).$ As $h\to 0$ then the middle term in the inequality becomes $f'_{-}(x)$ although I am not sure what happens to the remaining terms. Any hints will be much appreicated.

Comment: What is $f'$ with the extra bar after it? [may be standard notation...]

Comment: @coffeemath The left derivative of $f$.

Comment: If it's the *left* derivative, I would have expected $[f(x)-f(x-h)]/h$ (where $h>0$) in the middle of your displayed inequality, after "We know that".

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'_-$ is continuous, it has a primitive $F$ of class $C^1$. Let $g=F-f$. Then $g'_-$ is identically $0$ on $(a,b)$. Now show that this implies that $g$ is constant.